# Bash - sed replacing text

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace a line of text in a properties file. 
For example:

```
food.type=banana
```

With this line of code I can replace banana entirely with another entered input.

```
FOOD=apple
sed "s/food.type=.*/food.type=$FOOD/"
```

Output:

```
food.type=apple
```

However when the previous line of text I'm trying to replace has a `/` in it, I can't get the replacement to work. 
For example:

```
food.type=/yellow/banana
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have to escape the slashes with \/ or use a different delimiter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slashes are being read as closing the reg-ex match/substitute patterns,

Do

```
sed "s@food.type=.*@food.type=$FOOD@"
```

Some seds require that you escape the first instance of a non-standard delimiter, ie

```
sed "s\@food.type=.*@food.type=$FOOD@"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: A point of interest here is that you can use *any* character as he regex delimiter in this way. Other common choices include `|`, `\ `, and `:` depending on the text to be dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to keep using `/` as sed's delimiter, and escape any slashes in the replacement string.  bash can do this (although it's a but cryptic):

```
sed "s/food.type=.*/food.type=${FOOD//\//\/}/"
```

That variable substitution is rather cryptic, so let me break it down explain it piece by piece:

`${FOOD`  Start a variable substitution of FOOD
`//`  replacing all occurrences of
`\/`  the character `/` (note that it must be escaped in this context)
`/`  with...
`\/`  the replacement string `\/` (note that the escape here is simply treated as part of the replacement string)
`}`  end of substitution

But this isn't entirely perfect, as there are several other characters that might cause trouble if they occur in the replacement string.  To really bulletproof this, you can either do several replacements in bash (messy), or farm the job out to `sed`:

```
ESCAPEDFOOD="$(printf "%s" "$FOOD" | sed 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')"
sed "s/food.type=.*/food.type=$ESCFOOD/"
```

Again, the substitution gets a bit cryptic, so here's a breakdown:

`s/`  Replace the pattern
`[\/&]`  any of the characters `\`, `/`, or `&`
`/`  with...
`\\&`  the replacement string `\` (escaped here) followed by the original match
`/g`  ...globally (i.e. replace all occurrences)

(And yes, I'm aware of the irony of using `sed` to prepare a string for use with `sed`.)

Note that it's possible I missed some troublesome characters; if so, they can be added to the `[]` expression.